# Why I got a NullPointerException when using initializeState() in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am using operator state with CheckpointedFuntion, however I encountered NullPointerException while initializing a MapState:

```java
public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {
    MapStateDescriptor<Long, Long> descriptor
        = new MapStateDescriptor<>(
            "state",
            TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Long>() {}),
            TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Long>() {})
        );
    state = context.getKeyedStateStore().getMapState(descriptor);
}
```

I got the NullPointerException when I assign "descriptor" to getMapState()

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at fyp.Buffer.initializeState(Iteration.java:51)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:259)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:694)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:682)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Which Flink version? And the NPE appear when you create the `MapStateDescriptor<>()` and not while `context.getKeyedStateStore().getMapState(descriptor)`?

Comment: Could you also post the stacktrace that you get?

Comment: Are you actually applying this stateful operator to a keyed stream (in other words, are you keying your stream before calling the former operator)?

Comment: @TobiSH I am using Flink 1.4. I encounter the Exception at "state = context.getKeyedStateStore().getMapState(descriptor)"

Comment: @spi-x-i Actually no. I am not using a keyed state but an operator state. But I have to use some map-like state to keep some intermediate value.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're bumping into a NPE due to the fact you're attempting to access the `KeyedStateStore` documented [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/state/KeyedStateStore.html); but, since you haven't a keyed stream, there is no such state store available along your job.

> Gets a handle to the system's key/value state. The key/value state is  only accessible if the function is executed on a KeyedStream. On each access, the state exposes the value for the key of the element currently processed by the function. Each function may have multiple partitioned states, addressed with different names.

So if you implement `CheckpointedFunction` (documented [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointedFunction.html)) on an unkeyed upstream (and you won't it) you should consider to access the operator state store

```
snapshotMetadata = context.getOperatorStateStore.getUnionListState(descriptor)
```

The [operator state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/state/state.html#operator-state) allows you to have one state per parallel instance of your job, conversely to the keyed state which each state instance depends on the keys produced by a keyed stream.

Note that in the above example we request `.getUnionListState` that will outcome all the parallel instances of your operator state (formatted as a list of states).

If you look for a concrete example you can give a shot to this [source](https://github.com/FlinkML/flink-jpmml/blob/master/flink-jpmml-scala/src/main/scala/io/radicalbit/flink/pmml/scala/api/functions/EvaluationCoFunction.scala): it is an operator implementing an operator state.

At the end, if you need a keyed stream instead, so you might think to move your solution closer to [keyed state Flink backend](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/state/state.html#keyed-state).